# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: xcodebuild was not found

Tags: ios, ionic3, emulation, xcodebuild

Recently I created an app in ionic and I wanted to test it in ios. So I run the command `ionic cordova emulate ios` . But, It is giving me following error.

> (node:4200) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: xcodebuild was not found. Please install version 7.0.0 or greater from App Store

I also run following commands but it still shows same error.

```
 npm install -g ios-sim
```

and

```
npm install -g ios-deploy
```

Please guide me what to do. 
**NOTE:** I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: are you using MacOS?

Comment: No, I am using ubuntu 16.04

Comment: You are getting this error because you are running this command on Linux this command require MacOS with Code installed machine. Hope this will help you :)

Comment: @ivarun but Can I  emulate only in ubuntu?

Comment: @ivarun Is there any ways that I can test how it works in ios (emulator)

Comment: No, You can test only on MacOS. You can also install MacOS on vm machine and test if you don’t have mac machine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170892/discussion-between-riddhi-and-ivarun).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting an error because you are running this command on Linux you need macOS to run this command. Hope this will help you :)